# How i jump to the next row in a table on an if condition w/o <tr>?

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to make a calendar table which uses a condition to jump to next row everytime (`DayOfTheWeek = Sunday`), but i cant use `<tr>` because Google Chrome doesn't assimilate it.

Sorry cant include other parts of the code, but its confidential.

```
@*Html Part *@


 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr style="background-color:black">

        <td align="center" style="color:white">Lunes</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Martes</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Miercoles</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Jueves</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Viernes</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Sabado</td>
        <td align="center" style="color:white">Domingo</td>

    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @for (int a = 1; a < dayOfWeekFirst; a++)
        {
            <td align="center"> </td>
        }

        @for (int i = 1; i <= daysInCurrentMonth; i++)
        {
            DateTime renderedDay = new DateTime(firstDay.Year, firstDay.Month, i);

            <td align="center">@i</td>
            if (renderedDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                //// Next Row
                <tr /> 
            } 
        }
        @for (int a = 1; a <= 7 - dayOfWeekLast; a++)
        {
            <td align="center"> </td>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where do you start the <tr> in your <tbody> section. Shouldn't you have a <tr> to start the row in order for the </tr> to be relevant?

Comment: i just need the <tr /> for the table to drop to the next row. unless there's other way to jump to the next row :S

Comment: I don't believe <tr /> is valid, it's expected to have cell elements. Have you tried... <tr><td> </td></tr>?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the `<tr />` is allowed as a row is expected to have cell elements.

Try adding an empty cell.

```
if (renderedDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    //// Next Row
    <tr><td> </td></tr>
}
```

EDIT, then try closing the element with a closing tag. The `tr` element is not void-element in HTML so you shouldn't use `<tr />.`

```
if (renderedDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    //// Next Row
    <tr></tr>
}
```

Comment: if i add another <td> it will add another blank space, which i dont need, and yes, you can use <tr /> alone and it will just drop you to next row (Mozilla,Microsoft Edge), it's just in Chrome that it gets messy.

Comment: Regardless if one or more browsers work with your html, it doesn't mean it's valid html. Enter your html in this w3c validator and see what it says... https://validator.w3.org/nu/